# How to send a users email address with a socket connection?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Im using socket.io, i need to send the users email address in the same instant that they connect to the socket.

I want to do something like this:(using vue)

```
//On the client side
data () {
    return{
        userEmail: 'test@gmail.com'
        socket: io('localhost:5000/messages', {userEmail: this.userEmail})
    }
}

//On the server
io.on('connection', function(socket, data){
    socket.email = data.userEmail
})
```

Comment: 1. You can't use `this.userEmail` like that to refer to a neighboring key 2. you need to connect first, data is sent using the `socket` returned by `io()` - I'd open the connection in `mounted()`, then simply send the email right away

Comment: @ChrisG OK ill try that